# radio control with arduino

Tags: arduino, servo, radio-transmission

Hi I am attempting to read from an rc transmitter using an Arduino Uno board, I have a signal pin connected from the receiver to pin 9 on the Arduino. Here is the code I would really appreciate some help all I am trying to achieve is the read the pmw from the receiver. I am able to plug a servo into the receiver and that works fine along with a motor I am just struggling when I try and use the Arduino with the receiver. When I run my program all I get in the Serial monitor are values such as 9991,9972,10030,10050 that are completely unrelated.

I want to have a pmw value that I can map to 0-255 in order to control a motor

My [Circuit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JjMWM.jpg):
battery -> ESC(for BEC to regulate five volts back to receiver)-> receiver -> ch3 signal pin -> Arduino uno (pin9)

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  int pwm = pulseIn(9, HIGH, 25000);
  Serial.println(pwm);
  delay (5);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using [`pulseIn`](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/advanced-io/pulsein/) which returns a **time** (in ms). The time being how long it waited for a HIGH signal. If you want the actual value, use [`analogRead`](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/analog-io/analogread/). You can still use `pulseIn`, just don't use the return value

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  byte pwm = analogRead(A5) / 4;
  Serial.println(pwm);
  delay(5);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help however this still does not return a value that has anything to do with the signal from the controller have you got anymore suggestions?

Comment: @OliverM Try omitting pulseIn completely

Comment: Hi thanks again for the help however i completely cut out the pulseIn line however i am now just getting different random values such as 370 but nothing changes as i move the sticks

Comment: Could you edit your question and include your wiring? It would also help if you included what exactly you are expecting.

Comment: I have included the wiring and what i want to finally be able to achieve is to have the Arduino receiving values from the receiver in order to later control a motor or a servo ect.

Comment: If you want a value from 0-255, just divide pwm by 4. Also, an actual picture of the circuit would be better.

Comment: I have now included a picture of the circuit and if i divide the value by four i will again just get random numbers as the value is just consistently around 400 which does not change when i move the stick. The current problem is that i cannot read the pwm value

Comment: You need to plug the yellow wire into the analog pins (A0 - A5) and I will update the code using A5.

Comment: Thanks again for the help but it still isn't working once i have plugged to yellow wire into A5 have you got any more suggestions

Comment: Are you sure that the receiver is on?

Comment: Yup if I plug the signal pin into the servo it works perfectly so that means the only problem is reading form the arduino

Comment: With the receiver plugged into the servo, does moving the joysticks on the controller have any effect?

Comment: Yes when I plug the signal pin into the servo it moves as it should

Comment: So what do you need the Arduino for?

Comment: Because I am attempting to be able to use the arduino to be able to override the servos to make an auto avoidance system

Comment: I don't see the problem. Remember: copy and paste my exact code into Arduino IDE, Receiver output pin to Analog Pin A5. If that doesn't work, try posting on [the Arduino forums](https://forum.arduino.cc/) or [Arduino stackexchange](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/)